# How do I alter the drop-down navigation menu in Oslo?

Tags: 2013

I managed to alter the font-size of the words on the navigation bar thru

`.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox {
    font-size: 20px;
}`

but I want to change the width of the drop-down menu so that it conforms to the size of the largest item in the menu.

For example, the largest item in this list is "continuous improvement", and I would like for the width of the drop-down menu to be just large enough to keep that item on one line to lesser the confusion of which words are grouped together:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need following CSS.

```
ul.dynamic {
  width: auto !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```